# Issue running an script block in powershell to get csv output

Tags: powershell

In powershell running the below code in a script block and having issue running it

```
foreach($list in $an){
    Write-Host "on loop :" $loop
    Write-Host "Checking on VM : "$list.vm
    $checkdata = (([datetime]$currentdate) - ([datetime]$list.Created.ToString().split(" ")[0])).Days
    Write-Host "Check data " $checkdata
    IF($checkdata -gt 2){
        Write-Host "on Dupe : " $dupe
        #$datecreated = $sizeinGGB = $diff = $null | Out-Null
        $datecreated = ($list.Created.ToString().split(" ")[0]) 
        Write-Host $datecreated
        $sizeinGGB = [INT]$list.SizeGB
        Write-Host $sizeinGGB
        $diff =  ((([datetime]$currentdate) - ([datetime]$list.Created)).Days) 
        Write-Host $diff
        $repo =  [ordered] @{
            vm = $list.vm
            SNapshotname = $list.Name
            DateCreated = $datecreated
            Snapshotold =  $diff
            SizeinGB = $sizeinGGB
        }
        New-Object PSobject -Property $repo
        $dupe ++
    }ELSE{
        Write-Host $list.vm " : Looks Good"
    }
    $loop ++
}
```

If I remove the $repo assignment statement my script is working good. If I put that on the script then script just stop execution on $repo block

Comment: Sounds like you're running PS2.0 which doesn't support `[ordered]` type accelerator.

Comment: To see which Powershell version you are running, use `(get-host).Version`.

Comment: Version 5
Build 10586

Comment: @SUN `script just stop execution on $repo block` - do you get an error message?

Comment: No Error message, it's stuck in the loop for more than an hr with no processing

Comment: Do you get any output? If so please post a snippet

Comment: Did some write-host in between,

But does;t like the repo and it is not going further after Repo block and $repo is not saving any output.

Comment: Modified the code little
 Write-Host "Trying to create new opbect"
                        New-Object -Type PSobject -Property $repo
                        $repo =  [ordered] @{
                                                           }
Below is what I got ::::: from the logs

Trying to create new opbect
System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
Done creating new boject
on loop : 1
Checking on VM :  xxxxxxxxxxx
Check data  437
on Dupe :  1
0
436
Trying to create new opbect